# Missing (;) operator error

Tags: sql, ms-access

```
INSERT INTO Table2 ( [Acct Numb], SubInfo, [Asset Mkt Val], [Acct Asset MV]) 
Values (t1t2.[Acct Root] & "01", t1t2.SubInfo, t1t2.[SumOfAsset Mkt Val], (SELECT SUM(t1t3.[SumOfAsset Mkt Val]) 
FROM Table1Totals t1t3 
WHERE t1t3.[Acct Root]=t1t2.[Acct Root])) 
From Table1Totals t1t2 
WHERE t1t2.[Acct Suffix] in '*0[134789]' and t1t2.[SubInfo] not in ('01 PART OF SUB ACCT');
```

When I am trying to execute this expression I am getting popup message : "Missing Semicolon(;) at the end of the expression and it is pointing to "From" (1st one).

Any suggestion.

Comment: What SQL is this, MS, Oracle, Access, etc?

Comment: I've added a tag for it then :)

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**

The WHERE clause of the subquery is referencing t1t2 which only exists outside the subquery

```
WHERE t1t3.[Acct Root]=t1t2.[Acct Root]
```

t1t2 doesn't exist

Comment: I have checked for that. So when I am removing the extra bracket it is giving me missing operator.

Comment: Do you have any idea how can I implement it then? Thanks.

Comment: Given that you haven't explained what you are trying to achieve with the query, not easily.